# How to decrease screen time data on iOS?

Tags: ios, screen-time

Parents of my friend make her show her screen time every day. Important: they haven't set any limits, they check screen time every day manually. 
How can she decrease screen time data? For example, on Android I can uninstall an app and screen time will be decreased for time I was using this app. But this doesn't work on iOS. **What other ways are possible to bypass screen time on iOS?**  
 If important, my friend's phone is iPhone 7+

Comment: Frame challenge: your friend has asked you to help her lie to her parents. Is it right that you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I'm not recommending she do this, considering its quite a bit of work just to lie about screen time. But depending on her phones [OS version](https://pangu8.com/jailbreak/iphone/#iphone-7), the 7 Plus can be jailbroken. She would likely use https://checkra.in/ or https://unc0ver.dev/

Then she could use [Cydia to install a tweak](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/npdwbx/request_a_tweak_to_change_the_screen_time_values/) such as MilkyWay (open app without its screen time being registered), ScreenTimeFaker (although people claim this one breaks the settings app), or Ersatz (although this one you'd have to manually edit the screen time number in the Phones OS data).

Backup the phone before jailbreaking, a full restore (reset + reinstall OS from laptop) can undo the effects of it if needed. I haven't personally done this tweak so its at your own risk, but have done many others.

To make this answer whole, I must add that **using your phone all the time is really unhealthy and changes the wiring in your brain**, and that her parents are justified.

Comment: Thx, I'll tell her this solution